# The probability that 1st player wins

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

A deck of $4$ cards with values $\{1,2,3,4\}$ on each. **A** and **B** pull each one after another a card without putting it back in the deck. The winner is the one who pulls a $sum≥4$ first. A starts the game. What is the probability that A wins?

I tried to observe the cases that A won't win: $\{1,2\};\{2,1\}$ plus when B pull $4$ on his first try. There are $3$ out of $8$ choices $(4×2)\ldots 1-(3/8)=0.625$

Comment: @Henry I tried to observe the cases that A won't win: {1,2};{2,1} plus when B pull 4 on his first try. There are 3 out of 8 choices (4×2)… 1-(3/8)=0.625

Comment: @Henry OR simply `1/4` for win at A's first pull + `1/3*1/3` win at second pull… 0.361

Comment: As Henry seems to be suggesting, there's isn't really a compact, one-term solution, but you just look at a few cases. The first thing I see is to ask, what are the cards $A$ will draw? That is, what are the first and third card in the deck? If they are $\{1,2\}$, they won't sum to $4$, and in any other case they will. However, even if $A$'s cards sum to $4$, $B$ can still win by drawing $4$ first. This shows an easier solution- how many ways can $B$ win and $A$ lose? There are only two cases of this- $A$'s cards are $\{1,2\}$, or $A$'s cards aren't $\{1,2\}$ but $B$ draws $4$ first.

Comment: It looks like you've tried the same thing, but your mistake is that you treat $A$ getting $\{1,2\}$ and $B$ pulling $4$ first as disjoint cases, when it's possible for both events to occur. Thus, you either have to consider the case of $A$ getting $\{1,2\}$, and the case of $A$ not getting $\{1,2\}$ but $B$ getting $4$ first, which are disjoint, or subtract the size of the intersection of those two cases to avoid double counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, you write (you should always put your attempt in your original post, BTW):

> I tried to observe the cases that A won't win: {1,2};{2,1} plus when B pull 4 on his first try. There are 3 out of 8 choices (4×2)… 1-(3/8)=0.625

There are two problems with this:

First, you count the '$(1,2)$' event, the '$(2,1)$' event, and the event that $B$ picks $4$ all as $1$ event. That is, you give them all 'equal weight' and thus consider them equally likely. However, that is not the case:

The '$(1,2)$' event, which is the '$A$ loses because $A$ picks $1$ and then $2$' event, can only happen when $B$ picks the $3$ on the first pick instead of the $4$, because otherwise the game would be over. So, the '$(1,2)$' event really represents only $1$ possible permutation of the $4$ cards: $(1,3,2,4)$. Likewise for the '$(2,1)$' event, which represents the single permutation $(2,3,1,4)$.

On the other hand, the '$B$ picks $4$' event covers many possible permutations, e.g. $(1,4,2,3)$, but also $(1,4,3,2)$ (even though the game ends after the $4$), but also $(2,4,1,3), (2,4,3,1), (3,4,1,2)$, and $(3,4,2,1)$. So, the '$A$ loses because $B$ picks $4$' event represents $6$ possible permutations, not just $1$.

Second, you suggest that there are $8$ choices ... but what are those $8$ choices? There are $24$ permutations of the $4$ cards, so that's what you need to use as the denominator. And, as shown above, there are $8$ possible permutations that leads to $A$ losing. So, the probability that $A$ loses is:

$$\frac{8}{24}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Actually the $P("A wins")$ was asked (final answer $1-⅓$) but clearly answered, learned a lot out of it! Thanks.

Comment: @RoxcH Glad I could help :)